# Problems saving a class method into txt

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby and make a lot of mistakes, so I hope people who are experienced in ruby can share a bit of knowledge. 
I can't figure out how I can make ruby save the text into a txt file that a method `all` writes.

```
class generator
  def all
    puts "i want to save this text into a txt file"
  end
end
new_gen = generator.new
new_gen.all

my_file = File.new("Story.txt", "a+")
my_file.puts("all")
my_file.puts("\n")
my_file.close
```

I tried everything, but the txt file either has the "all" in it or it's completely blank. Any ideas? I also tried `my_file.puts(all)` and `my_file.puts(new_gen.all)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `Generator` to do the writing you could pass it an [`IO`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html) object.

```
class Generator
  def initialize(io)
    @io = io
  end

  def all
    @io.puts "i want to save this text into a txt file"
  end
end

# write to STDOUT
gen = Generator.new(STDOUT)
gen.all

# write to file
File.open("Story.txt", "a+") do |file|
  gen = Generator.new(file)
  gen.all
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You method should simply return a string. Puts displays the string, does not return it. So change the class to:

```
class generator
  def all
    "i want to save this text into a txt file" # optionally add a return
  end
end
new_gen = generator.new
new_gen.all
```

Then use the last version you tried: `my_file.puts(new_gen.all)`

Comment: How can i add a return? and what does a return do? Sorry am just new to ruby and don't know all the comands.

Comment: @user2197491 A return statement specifies what is the return value of a method/function. IN ruby however the last executed statement's return value is by default the return value of the method/function as well so you don't need a return here(still you can add it for readability and maintainability). You add the return here by modifying the line `"i want to ...txt file"` to `return "i want to... txt file"` i.e. prepend a `return ` to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Generator
  def all
    "i want to save this text into a txt file"
  end
end

gen = Generator.new

f = File.new("Story.txt", "a+")
f.puts gen.all
f.close
```